# multiple radio group give short cut key in keyboard for each radio button for each group java swing

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, radio-group, jradiobutton

I have radio many radio group in my application and each group has many radio button i want to know how it is possible to assign one key board short cut or a combination of keyboard short cut for each button for example i want to put number 1 in first group first radio button so if i select the first group and press 1 in keyboard automatically first radio button will be selected. I am doing it now by tab, when i tab i select the focus radio button but it is not good when there are so many radio button because it takes time if i tab until the last radio button. How is this possible any suggestion is accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`AbstractButton.setMnemonic(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic-char-).

My bad..

> This method is now obsolete, please use **`setMnemonic(int)`** to set the mnemonic for a button.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  See edit (which BTW - you should notice includes the same text you referred to, and ***give the replacement method***).

Comment: 1 more question i need to put the KeyPress event in the form itself not in the button right?

Comment: A mnemonic added to a button (or menu item) will work.  The 'form' has no concept of mnemonics, though it is possible to add a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) that activates the button, it is easier to just add the mnemonic.

Comment: so when ever i press the specified mnemonic button it will select the assigned radiobutton? thank for the idea