# Add a character (or a String) when enter is pressed (in a JTextPane)

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

So I have a **JTextPane** and I added a keyListener, like that I can know if the enter button was pressed :

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                // add there the code to add a character to the textPane!
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

But now I am bloked, how to **add a character '}'** to the textPane? 
(not anywhere, just after the cursor's position, to the following...)

Comment: Never use a KeyListener with a text component such as JTextPane. If you want to listen for ENTER keypress, use Key Bindings -- or a DocumentListener or perhaps here a DocumentFilter.

Comment: This questions answer has the solution you seek I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above by @HovercraftFullOfEels, don't use a `KeyListener` to listen to the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, instead use [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) or a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html). Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40944215/2180785) from Hovercraft that uses Key Bindings, though it's not with a `JTextPane` but you can take the general idea from there.

To append text in the caret position, you could try [`JTextPane#replaceSelection(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#replaceSelection(java.lang.String)) which from the docs:

> Replaces the currently selected content with new content represented by the given string. **If there is no selection this amounts to an insert of the given text**. If there is no replacement text this amounts to a removal of the current selection. The replacement text will have the attributes currently defined for input at the point of insertion. If the document is not editable, beep and return.